# Need some Help In wowza media product with Live Streaming

Tags: flash, mobile, amazon-ec2, wowza

I've some issue with planning on how to get wowza working for my case.I'm trying to get my video chat working using wowza and AWS EC2. I've two websites, one is for  users that share their computer's camera and microphone and initiate a broadcast to the second website users. The second website has a flash player which shows the live feed obtained from the first website. Meaning whatever a user are broadcasting using their camera and mic. 
Now I've to use wowza to first get the second websites flash player feed, which is coming live from the first website. My goal is to view the live feed of the user to a mobile website version. 
Advance Thank you for your support.

Comment: "Questions" that are merely requirements without showing any effort [are subject to removal](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/270903/2596334). They were once considered [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Many people consider it to be rude, so please try to [follow the guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). Thanks.

Comment: True, this is not a question. Did you try anything based on the docs?

Answer (score 0):

There is a [complete example](https://github.com/jantekb/wowzatoolbox-examples) that you can start with on GitHub. It contains a Wowza configuration Application.xml configured for mobile streaming as well. It is a demo for a product called Wrench, but you can leave that out if you don't want user authentication in your system.